# WebAPI proper way to set Authorization token Expiration

Tags: http-headers, authorization, asp.net-web-api

In an expected WebAPI, the server generates an encrypted token and pass it back to the client.

My initial thoughts would point to these possible scenarios:

1. Add the datetime expiration to the token and resend it back to the client at every call?
2. Add the token on a static server list and update it at every call?
3. Store the token on the server Database and check/update it at every call?

I don't know if I'm missing any other way to achieve the same ...

What are the pro-cons of each way?
Which way is the recommended one?

This is my first post so I'm hoping I'm asking the right questions in the right way.